# Change picture background image

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, overlay

What I am trying to achieve is to take a picture using iPhone camera and then replace part of the picture with some other pictures...I was thinking of taking the picture and then overlaying it with a UIView with low alpha but then I would not be able to replace only certain parts of the picture. If you can give me some ideas I would be really gradeful.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS there are several APIs for images, and I understand your confusion.
First you have `UIImage`, the CocoaTouch abstraction for images.
Then you have `CGImage`, the CoreGraphics abstraction for images.
And additionally you have `CIImage`, the CoreImage abstraction for images.

These are all different entities that can not be used together in a nice bridge-free way. Instead, you have to convert to and from the different formats.

Typically, what you want in the end is a UIImage that you can display in a widget. You can create this image from either a `CGImage` or a `CIImage`. `CIImage` contains advanced filter functionality, which would for instance allow you to put another image on top as you describe using an appropriate composition filter.

`CIImage` is faster and better in any way, however it is still not fully supported in iOS. You may not yet create your own custom filters for iOS, and only a fraction of the filters are yet to be supported.

Hence I would recommend using `CGImage` for this purpose. You need to render into a new render context and then create an UIImage from that render context.

This should do the trick:

```
UIImage *originalImage = ...;
UIImage *frontImage = ...;
CGSize destinationSize = originalImage.frame.size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationSize);
[originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,destinationSize.width,destinationSize.height)];
[originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(10,10,destinationSize.width - 20,destinationSize.height - 20)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

am explaining you in points
1. use quartzcore library
2. convert both the images to ciimage.
 code for conversion is : (there are many , am siting one of the many)

```
 CIImage *paper1 =[CIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation( [UIImage imageNamed:@"heart123.png"], 1)];
```

Now, use Filters according to Your need,
like.. "CISourceAtopCompositing" or "CISourceOverCompositing" filters
and you get what you want

code for using them is :

```
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

   CIFilter filter= [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceAtopCompositing"];  //for CISourceAtopCompositing method
    [filter setDefaults];
    [filter setValue:sourceImage forKey:@"inputImage"]; 
    [filter setValue:backgroundImage forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];
```

Here both backgroundImage, and sourceImage are CIImage converted from UIImage

Now to get the uiimage after edit use this code

```
 CIImage *outputImage = [filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
 CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
 UIImage *outputUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```